# Select all clients that have made a reservation each month in the previous year

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Conceptual Model]

I have to make an sql query that shows all the info of the clients that have made a reservation every single month in the last year, I thought about using a Group by Month and then count the number of groups.

Like this: (I didn't know how to count the number of groups)

```
Select *

From Cliente 

inner join Persona 

on Cliente.CEDULA = Persona.CEDULA

inner join Reserva

on Cliente.cedula = Reserva.CEDULA

Group BY DATEPART(MONTH, Reserva.FECHAINICIO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `cedula` identifies the client, you do not need all the joins.  Then the key is the date arithmetic part and aggregation:

```
select r.cedula
from Reserva r
where r.fechainicio >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') - interval '1' year and
      f.fechainicio < trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')
group by r.cedula
having count(distinct trunc(r.fechainicio, 'MM')) = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you search for `count()`?

```
Select DATEPART(MONTH, Reserva.FECHAINICIO), count(*)

From Cliente 

inner join Persona 

on Cliente.CEDULA = Persona.CEDULA

inner join Reserva

on Cliente.cedula = Reserva.CEDULA

Group BY DATEPART(MONTH, Reserva.FECHAINICIO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with bellow query, Put relevant column names for client.id_column, date_column

```
Select Month, COUNT(<<client.id_column>>) TotalCount
From Cliente
inner join Persona
on Cliente.CEDULA = Persona.CEDULA
inner join Reserva
on Cliente.cedula = Reserva.CEDULA
where  Reserva.<<date_column>>  >= '2017-01-01' 
AND     Reserva.<<date_column>>  <= '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Reserva.<<date_column>>), 0), as Month;
```